# Different iCloud and iTunes accounts on one device

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, icloud, apple-id

I recently got divorced. My ex-husband has changed the Apple ID password for his account and won't share it with me. All three of my boys are on his account. I can no longer see them on Find My iPhone, or have any access to their texts, web browsing history, etc. As their mother I need that. I want to know if I can create a separate Apple ID for them, use it as their iCloud account, but use my ex-husband's account for their iTunes so they can still have access to all the music, movies, and apps they have accumulated over the years.

Any help anyone can give me would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are separate places in settings for iCloud accounts and iTunes accounts.  You can be signed into different accounts there.  You will need the current iCloud password to sign out of that account in order change to a different one if Find My iPhone is turned on.

Comment: Thank you, Charley! Will I have access to my ex's music movies and apps in this scenario? I don't want it and he doesn't either.